# Update utilizando valores contidos em outra tabela

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, firebird

Como posso fazer um update em uma tabela setando o valor de um campo com o mesmo valor contido em outra tabela para todos os registros?

Tenho uma tabela 'produto' e uma tabela 'movproduto'.
Quero atualizar a informação referente ao preço de custo na tabela 'produto' com o mesmo valor contido na tabela 'movproduto'.

```
tabela 'produto'
codproduto
vlrprecocusto

tabela 'movproduto'
codproduto
vlrprecocusto
```

Tentei de alguns modos e não obtive exito.
Exemplo de como estava tentando:

```
update produto p 
inner join movproduto m on m.codproduto = p.codproduto
    set p.vlrprecocusto = m.vlrprecocusto;
```

Esta sql retorna o seguinte erro:

```
token unknown - line 2, column 5
inner
```

Estou utlizando firebird 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
update produto p
set
  p.vlrprecocusto = (select 
                       m.vlrprecocusto
                     from movproduto m 
                     where 
                       (m.codproduto = p.codproduto))
```

**Explicação**

Para cada registro na tabela "produto" será selecionado o registro de mesmo código na tabela "movproduto"; O valor do campo "vlrprecocusto" da tabela "movproduto" será gravado no campo "vlrprecocusto" da tabela "produto".

**Atenção**

- Se nenhum registro com o mesmo código for localizado na tabela "movproduto" será gravado NULL na "produto"; Se desejar evitar o NULL pode-se utilizar a função COALESCE, mas se desejar que "produto" sem "movproduto" não sofra alteração, então deve-se incluir na cláusula WHERE uma condição para afetar apenas registros que existam na "movproduto".
- Se houver registros duplicados com o mesmo "codproduto" na tabela "movproduto" ocorrerá o erro "multiple rows in singleton select". Para resolver isso você pode usar "FIRST 1" no sub-select ou usar GROUP BY com a função AVG no campo "vlrprecocusto" da tabela "movproduto".

Qualquer dúvida, pergunte.

Comment: Consegui do modo que descreveu. Ótimo, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Cara infelizmente o FIREBIRD não aceita update com inners...

Você teria que fazer algo +/- assim

```
update produto set vlrprecocusto = valor;
  where codproduto in (select codproduto 
                         from produto
                        inner join movproduto m on m.codproduto = p.codproduto)
```

Obs.: Confira meu update antes de rodar ele para não danificar seus dados, caso eu tenha colocado alguma informação errada.

**Editado**

Me desculpe, no exemplo acima mostrei apenas a estrutura sem me atentar aos campos, ela serviria para você setar um valor fixo para o campo codproduto...

No caso para fazer o update que você quer teria que fazer assim

```
EXECUTE BLOCK AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE iCodProduto INTEGER;
  DECLARE VARIABLE nValorCusto NUMERIC(18,4);
BEGIN
  FOR select p.codproduto 
            ,m.vlrprecocusto
        from      produto    p
       inner join movproduto m on m.codproduto = p.codproduto INTO :iCodProduto, :nValorCusto DO
  BEGIN
    update produto set vlrprecocusto = :nValorCusto where codproduto = :iCodProduto;
  END
END;
```

Se você estiver rodando esse script em algum projeto que esteja fazendo, veja se o componente que você utiliza aceita o `execute block`, por exemplo, a TIBQuery do delphi 7 não rodaria esse script, mas se estiver executando diretamente no banco, ai roda sem problemas.

Comment: Certo. Tentei do modo que você sugeriu. Porém retorna erro:
'Column unknown
m.vlrprecocusto
At line 1, column 42'

Comment: Editei minha resposta, verifique se a solução resolve